# AngularJS Route-Provider not working

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I am new to AngularJS and trying to build a single-page website based on the tutorial of Charney Kaye. Now I have set up the website as far as I understood it and it starts as intendet, however the navigation does not seem to load the qequested partial but tries to reference a path to a new full html file.

I'm sure I just missed a tiny thing, but I don't seem to be able to put a pin in it. So I'd be greatfull for any hint I might get.

The code I've done so far:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>

        <!-- Meta-Information -->
        <title>Zanas Wetter</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="ACME Inc.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Vendor: Bootstrap Stylesheets http://getbootstrap.com -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vondor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vondor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vondor/fonts_awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
        <link href="../vendor/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Our Website CSS Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    </head>
    <body ng-app="WeatherApp">
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade
            your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Our Website Content Goes Here -->
        <div ng-include='"templates/header.html"'></div>
        <div ng-view></div>

        <!-- Vendor: Angular, followed by our custom Javascripts -->
        <script src="/vendor/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/vendor/angularjs/angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Our Website Javascripts -->
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
        <script src="../vendor/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../vendor/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../data/morris-data.js"></script>

        <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
        <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

        <script src="../dist/js/jquery.formatDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../dist/js/wetterdienst.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <!-- Container -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fa fa-cloud fa-fw"></i> Weather App</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="tinkerforge">Station</a></li>
            <li><a href="datasearch">Datasearch</a></li>
                <li><a href="about">About</a>
                </li>
<!--            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Mein Profil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Nutzer Verwaltung</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Abmelden</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./Container -->
</nav>
```

main.js

```
/**
 * Main AngularJS Web Application
 */
var app = angular.module('WeatherApp', [
  'ngRoute'
]);

/**
 * Configure the Routes
 */
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    // Home
    .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    // Pages
    .when("about", {templateUrl: "partials/about.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("faq", {templateUrl: "partials/faq.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("datasearch", {templateUrl: "partials/datasearch.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("tinkerforge", {templateUrl: "partials/tinkerforge.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    .when("usercontrol", {templateUrl: "partials/usercontrol.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    // else 404
    .otherwise("/404", {templateUrl: "partials/404.html", controller: "PageCtrl"});
}]);

/**
 * Controls all other Pages
 */
app.controller('PageCtrl', function (/* $scope, $location, $http */) {
  console.log("Page Controller reporting for duty.");


});
```

Plus the requiered partials for the sites I wand to display. But as said before it doesn't try to load the partials but a path based on whatever literaly is written behind the `href=`

As I said, any help is welcome, so thank you for your time and reading so far.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `href="#/about"` The routing works with `#`

and if you use angular 1.6 add below for removing '!'

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

Comment: I had that #/ in an earlier attepmt, and tried is again, but it only results in the url changing from `http://127.0.0.1:8080/#!/` to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/#!/#%2Fabout` without anything happening to the displayed page.

Comment: I tried to copy your code iteratively into any of the given files but it did not change anything for me. Maybe I am missing some fundamental unterstanding for angular here.
Also triet do but int into one call like this  `App.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function AppConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider)` without any luck

Answer (score 0):

This is quiet embarresing, but the answer way in the order of the used JavaScript files in the index.html.

Putting the `<script src="js/main.js"></script>` in the last place seems to have fixed the problem.